# Unable to get Buildozer to work in ubuntu - "fatal error: arm-linux-gnueabi/python2.7/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: android, python, ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to build a very basic Hello World Android application using kivy. Source code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')  # update with your current version

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class DummyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Button(text="Hello World")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DummyApp().run()
```

I tried to build the app using Buildozer, using the command (along with [this](https://github.com/coderkd10/kivy_hello_world/blob/master/buildozer.spec) spec file):

```
buildozer android debug
```

But instead of building successfully I am getting the error -

> fatal error: arm-linux-gnueabi/python2.7/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory

I could find this and similar errors on many forums, but wasn't able to find any fix. The complete error log is as follows (obtained using log_level = 2 in spec file):

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian `dpkg' package management program version 1.17.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/kedia-abhishek/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/kedia-abhishek/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
# Android NDK found at /home/kedia-abhishek/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Check application requirements
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /home/kedia-abhishek/Desktop/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Available modules: android apsw audiostream bidi boost cherrypy c_igraph cprotobuf cymunk django docutils ecdsa enum34 evdev ffmpeg ffmpeg2 ffpyplayer freetype gevent greenlet harfbuzz hostpython igraph jpeg kivent_core kivent_cymunk kivy leveldb libevent libpq libsodium libswift libtorrent libxml2 libxslt libyaml lxml m2crypto midistream msgpack mysql_connector netifaces numpy opencv openssl paramiko pil plyer plyvel png polygon protobuf psutil psycopg2 pyasn1 pycrypto pygame pyjnius pylibpd pyopenssl pyparsing pyqrcode python pyyaml sdl setuptools six sqlalchemy sqlite3 storm swift thrift twisted txws wokkel zeroconf zope
# Application requirements already installed, pass
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /home/kedia-abhishek/Desktop/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Available modules: android apsw audiostream bidi boost cherrypy c_igraph cprotobuf cymunk django docutils ecdsa enum34 evdev ffmpeg ffmpeg2 ffpyplayer freetype gevent greenlet harfbuzz hostpython igraph jpeg kivent_core kivent_cymunk kivy leveldb libevent libpq libsodium libswift libtorrent libxml2 libxslt libyaml lxml m2crypto midistream msgpack mysql_connector netifaces numpy opencv openssl paramiko pil plyer plyvel png polygon protobuf psutil psycopg2 pyasn1 pycrypto pygame pyjnius pylibpd pyopenssl pyparsing pyqrcode python pyyaml sdl setuptools six sqlalchemy sqlite3 storm swift thrift twisted txws wokkel zeroconf zope
# Clean and build python-for-android
# Remove directory and subdirectory /home/kedia-abhishek/Desktop/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/helloworldapp
# Run './distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "helloworldapp"'
# Cwd /home/kedia-abhishek/Desktop/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Check build dependencies for Ubuntu
Packages missing: cython 
It might break the compilation, except if you installed thoses packages manually.
Check environment
SDK located at /home/kedia-abhishek/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
NDK located at /home/kedia-abhishek/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
NDK version is r9c
API level set to 14
Check NDK location
Check mandatory tools
Distribution will be located at /home/kedia-abhishek/Desktop/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/helloworldapp
Entering in ARM environment
Compiler found at /home/kedia-abhishek/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin//arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
PATH is /home/kedia-abhishek/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:/home/kedia-abhishek/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:/home/kedia-abhishek/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c:/home/kedia-abhishek/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools:/home/kedia-abhishek/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
Leaving ARM environment
Read kivy recipe
Module kivy depend on pygame pyjnius android
Read pygame recipe
Module pygame depend on python sdl
Read pyjnius recipe
Module pyjnius depend on python sdl
Read android recipe
Module android depend on pygame
Read python recipe
Module python depend on hostpython
Read sdl recipe
Module sdl depend on python
Ignored python, already processed
Ignored sdl, already processed
Ignored pygame, already processed
Read hostpython recipe
Ignored python, already processed
Modules changed to hostpython python sdl pygame pyjnius android kivy
Pure-Python modules changed to 
Run get packages
Download package for hostpython
Module hostpython already downloaded
Download package for python
Module python already downloaded
Download package for sdl
No package for sdl
Download package for pygame
Module pygame already downloaded
Download package for pyjnius
Module pyjnius already downloaded
Download package for android
No package for android
Download package for kivy
Module kivy already downloaded
Run prebuild
Call prebuild_hostpython
Call prebuild_python
Call prebuild_sdl
Call prebuild_pygame
Call prebuild_pyjnius
Call prebuild_android
Call prebuild_kivy
Run build
Skipped build_hostpython
Skipped build_python
Skipped build_sdl
Call build_pygame
Entering in ARM environment
Compiler found at /home/kedia-abhishek/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin//arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pygame.imageext' extension
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/kedia-abhishek/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/kedia-abhishek/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -I/home/kedia-abhishek/Desktop/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/jni/png -I/home/kedia-abhishek/Desktop/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/jni/jpeg -I/home/kedia-abhishek/Desktop/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl/include -I/home/kedia-abhishek/Desktop/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_mixer -I/home/kedia-abhishek/Desktop/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_ttf -I/home/kedia-abhishek/Desktop/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_image -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/imageext.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/imageext.o
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from src/pygame.h:75,
                 from src/imageext.c:47:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:15:52: fatal error: arm-linux-gnueabi/python2.7/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <arm-linux-gnueabi/python2.7/pyconfig.h>
                                                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'arm-linux-androideabi-gcc' failed with exit status 1
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "helloworldapp"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

#### NOTE:

1. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.
2. I followed [this](http://digitaljunky.io/make-a-snake-game-for-android-written-in-python-part-1/) tutorial and installed all the necessary dependencies as mentioned there.
3. Many forums suggested that I install "python-dev" or "python2.7-dev". Done that, but of no help.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best answer, but till a knowledgable person gives a better answer, I am keeping this as a placeholder.

You may want to try enabling multiarch, install python-dev and python2.7-dev for the architecture "arm-linux-gnueabi"